# can hibernatevalidator jar annotation validation and custom validation both be used together?

Tags: spring, validation

I have annotated html form class and I also wrote a custom validator class for the same form. is it possible to use both? After configuring the customValidation class, it doesnot hit the annotation based validation.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. thankyou.
I am defining the validator bean now as following

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

rest all of usual stuff of custom validation.
I changed the customvalidator class too
previously -

```
    public class CustomValidator implements Validator
```

Now -

```
    public class CustomValidator extends LocalValidatorFactoryBean implements Validator
```

thats it. now it is using/calling both.